# Getter returning old value

Tags: java, object, constructor, initialization

I recently ran into an issue with my object initialization.

I have a class (It is set up this way for persistent data storing and loading)

```
public class Example extends SuperExample{
    private String name = "";
    public Example(){
        super();
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    protected void load(){
        name = "Example";
    }
}

public abstract class SuperExample{
    protected abstract void load();
    public SuperExample(){
        //Do stuff
        load();
    }
}
```

The `getName()` that is called after the object is initialized is returning `""` and not `"Example"`.

Any idea what the root cause of this could be? If I were to set `name` in the constructor it works fine. But when it goes through the `super`, it errors.

```
Example e = new Example();
System.out.println(e.getName());
```

Comment: TL;DR: don't call overridable methods in the constructor.

Comment: Instance variable initialiser runs *after* super() calls. Do not call overridable methods from the constructor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407187/java-constructors-order-of-execution-in-an-inheritance-hierarchy

Comment: Ah ha, Thanks @lealceldeiro Found this after he mentioned. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are fields initialized before constructor code is run in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805547/are-fields-initialized-before-constructor-code-is-run-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

The initializer code: private String name = ""; runs AFTER the parent constructor.  Remove the initialization and it will work correctly.  But you shouldn't call overridable methods from constructors. :)

```
private String name;
```

instead of

```
private String name="";
```

Comment: In fact it is a **terrible** thing to use a protected load in the super constructor.

Comment: This doesn't make correct the fact of calling in a super class's constructor a method that is overridden by subclasses (the root cause of the problem here)

Comment: The overridden method is not the root cause of the problem.  It is not good programming practice, but the root cause of why name's value is overwritten is as I described.

Answer (score -1):

It's because the Example class method is protected I think. It's not callable from outside the class, so you're calling the superclass method. That does nothing so the value is still `""`. To check this, add a print statement to the load method and see if it's being called.

Comment: No. It is not related to this

Comment: Nope, that's not THE issue. Although it is a problem, indeed.