# JUnit BeforeAll vs static block - order of execution

Tags: java, junit

I have simple question. I have structure of classes like this: base class and child class(relationship is inheritance). @BeforeAll is from JUnit5.

```
 abstract class Base {
    static{
        System.out.println("A");
    }

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUp() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}


class Child extends Base {
    static {
        System.out.println("C");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("D");
    }
}
```

So, In my opinion, the order of execution should be: ACBD
but, this look like : ABCD
I was searching information, but I could not find anyting about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Constructors - Order of execution in an inheritance hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407187/java-constructors-order-of-execution-in-an-inheritance-hierarchy)

Comment: No, this is a another case :/

Comment: Note that it makes no difference whether `Base` is abstract or not.

Comment: Link to the `@BeforeAll` docs for reference (Junit5 5.4.0): [@BeforeAll](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.4.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/BeforeAll.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order is determined by Java classloading and JUnit5's `TestEngine` [1] (If I'm correct). So there's a difference between JUnit's test execution and Java's class loading.

### @BeforeAll vs static block

Remember difference between these two.

*static blocks* - are executed only once when Java's classloader loads the class in memory e.g. creating a first class instance.

`@BeforeAll` - methods are executed by JUnit's test engine before all tests in the current test class.

So if you would have another test class extending `Base` and run all tests, *static block* will be executed only once, whereas `@BeforeAll` twice (per each test class).

### Explanation of order

1. When JUnit executes the tests it instantiate your `Child`, which first needs to call a `Base`.
2. `"A"` - Java classloader has not loaded `Base` class yet, so it loads the class and - calls the *static block*.
3. `"B"` - JUnit's runner sees `@BeforeAll` annotation and checks wheter it has been called already and if not it calls the method.
4. `"C"` - Now Java can finish instatiation of `Child` so classloader can load it and calls the static block.
5. `"D"` - `Child` is initialized and method annotated by `@Test` is executed.

Now imagine there's another `class` e.g. `AnotherChild` extending `Base`. We are executing two test classes `Child` and `AnotherChild`, so JUnit has to call `@BeforeAll` **twice**, but Java already loaded `Base` class during execution of the first test class, so it will be called **only once**.

*Note, that this is roughly simplified situation and in reality it's a bit complicated (as usual).*

---

[1] https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.platform.engine/org/junit/platform/engine/TestEngine.html

Comment: The mystery is in point (3). How does JUnit insert itself into the JVM classloading process so that `Base.setUp()` is run before the class statics of `Child` are run? More interestingly, what kind of requirement might that solve? Note that if one overrides `setUp()` in `Child` without the `@BeforeAll` annotation, none of the `setUp()` is run. If one overrides `setUp()` in `Child` with the `@BeforeAll` annotation, only the `setUp()` of `Child` is run.